# How to return zero value record if no records when doing a group by on monthly data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create customer reports showing 12 months of data.  There is a `Billing_Month` field which is always set to the first day of the month e.g. 10/1/14.  Some customers will not always have data every month but I need to return a zero value for those months.

I think I'm close but it's just not quite working right.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT Sum(a.price) AS price, 
       Master_Account_Name, 
       b.Billing_Month 
FROM   tblbilling_detail_ec2 a 
       LEFT JOIN tblbilling_detail_ec2 b 
              ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE  master_account_name = 'TestCustomer' 
       AND b.billing_month BETWEEN Dateadd(yy, -1, '11/1/14') AND 
                                   Dateadd(m, -1, '11/1/14') 
GROUP  BY b.Billing_Month, 
          Master_Account_Name
```

Comment: Use a calendar- or number-table. Read: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Answer (score 0):

If all customers need to be returned, regardless of having activity or not, then you could use the customer table as the base table OR you can do an OUTER join to the customer table to make sure to grab all customers.

```
SELECT Sum(a.price) AS price, 
       cust.Master_Account_Name, 
       b.Billing_Month 
FROM   tblbilling_detail_ec2 a 
       LEFT JOIN tblbilling_detail_ec2 b 
              ON a.ID = b.ID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cust on a.master_account_name = cust.master_account_name
WHERE  a.master_account_name = 'TestCustomer' 
       AND b.billing_month BETWEEN Dateadd(yy, -1, '11/1/14') AND 
                                   Dateadd(m, -1, '11/1/14') 
GROUP  BY b.Billing_Month, 
      Master_Account_Name
```